# Notification icon size in Android

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I am trying to get information about the notification icon sizes to create them for my app but I am a little bit lost. I have read a few posts that basically says this:

```
For MDPI 24 px
For HDPI 36 px
For XHDPI 48 px
For XXHDPI 72 px
For XXXHDPI 96 px
```

I am trying to create my icons using Photoshop but I don't know the resolution. Can anyone tell what resolution I have to use?

Here you have a Photoshop, create New dialog:

[image]

Comment: "I don't know the resolution" -- um, you just typed them in. Create a 24x24 px edition of the icon and put it in `res/drawable-mdpi/`. Create a 36x36 px edition of the icon and put it in `res/drawable-hdpi/`. Etc. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Well yeah, but when I create a 24x24 image in photoshop it has also a resolution like 73 pixel per inch, or 150 or 300. What is the standard resolution?

Comment: I just edited the question and added an image from Photoshop

Comment: My guess is that Android does not use the resolution metadata, only the pixel data.

Answer (score 39):

you are right here.. 
Notification icons have the same size you had posted here... 
like

```
MDPI - 24 x 24  (drawable-mdpi)
HDPI - 36 x 36  (drawable-hdpi)
XHDPI - 48 x 48  (drawable-xhdpi)
XXHDPI - 72 x 72  (drawable-xxhdpi)
XXXHDPI - 96 x 96  (drawable-xxxhdpi)
```

For more detailed..  Here [Graphics Designer Cheat Sheet](http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/) Have a look

Comment: Better information than official Material guidelines, very nice. Although, something you might be interested in [Icon Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html)

Comment: @Jissay [Android Icon Reference Chart](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/) is an even better place.

Answer (score 5):

The correct resolutions have been posted already, but I want to point out that notification icons are unecessary for xxxhdpi devices. As per the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

> You should not use the xxxhdpi qualifier for UI elements other than the launcher icon.

Comment: I could not find the quote in the linked URL. Does this still apply?

Answer (score 5):

In case of the notification's large icon, the size is 64dp. So, the dimensions in pixels per density are:

MDPI: 64px
HDPI: 96px
XHDPI: 128px
XXHDPI: 192px
XXXHDPI: 256px

Comment: Your answer is correct! But, do you have any official doc references as well? Thanks!

Comment: Yap, here's the official Android documentation. Thanks for asking! https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this place to generate app or notification icons.
Here's [a link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=app_icon)!

Answer (score 1):

**Notification icon size in Android**

[image]