# How to find actual size of small notification icon at run time?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-icons

I know there's a list of different sizes for small notification icons for different screen DPIs, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29478847/673852). This is useful to know when preparing a set of static icon files for the application.

But I need to create an icon dynamically, using `setSmallIcon(Icon)` from `Notification.Builder`. For large icon, I can call e.g. `getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width)` and similar for height to get exact numeric values. How can I do the same for small icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small icon has a size of 24 dp. You can calculate the actual size in px at runtime.

Kotlin:

```
val smallIconSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24f, resources.displayMetrics)
```

Java:

```java
float smallIconSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())
```

If you don't have a context (to use `getResources`), you can use this as fallback:

```
val smallIconSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24f, Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics)
```